# How is the trajectory of a star found relative to the Sun?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, astronomy, stars, software

So i know we can get radial velocity by measuring blue shift and then we can use the distance to the star and its proper motion to get its tangential velocity. In the case of Bernards star, its expected to approach within 3.75 light years in 11800 years. How is the trajectory of the star calculated or plotted using just this information? Im trying to visualize this for my own understanding in python in 2d x-y coordinates. I have the following which correctly shows gliese 710 relative to the sun in the x-y plane:

```
    x = distance_now * np.cos(np.radians(dec_degrees)) * np.cos(np.radians(ra_degree))
    y = distance_now * np.cos(np.radians(dec_degrees)) * np.sin(np.radians(ra_degree))
```

I then plot this on the graph with the sun at poisiton (0,0). If i wanted to plot its trajectory to see how it passes closes the sun in 1.3 million years I would need to know its position in this plot at a few intervals and then connect them with a line. I know we can get radial velocity from blueshift and tangential velocity from proper motion and this can be used to find space/true velocity. But im not sure how this can be used to find its trajectory relative to the sun. I've clearly overlooked something important. Id appreciate some insight!

Comment: Maybe try asking on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're calling "space/true velocity" *is* velocity relative to the Sun. You're using observations in the solar reference frame without adjustment to another frame.

Velocity is always relative to some reference frame. There is no more objective "true" velocity.

Comment: ah yes, so how would i got about finding the direction of that space velocity?

Comment: @user2279603 You have the tangential velocity and the radial velocity, so just add those vectors.